# How to add a not null to an already existing column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I've setup a table in SQL Server 2008 Express and forgot to add a not null constraint to my unique `recordid` column. I tried to add it afterward, with this statement:

```
alter table movie_archive alter column RecordID Not null;
```

but it gives me an error message, saying there's a syntax error at "not". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ***do know*** that the entire SQL Server documentation is available online and for free? [Just head on over and look up `ALTER TABLE` ....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx)

Comment: FWIW, the second question listed as a dupe does not answer this question at all. It also pertains to MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql is a direct link to ALTER TABLE spec. There is a note about a necessity of using a column type when altering a column to NULL or NOT NULL. But without any reasons ((

Answer (score 18):

specify the datatype of the column

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INTEGER NOT NULL;

alter table movie_archive alter column RecordID INTEGER Not null;
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error message for this problem is there anything else you need to know before you can make a more informed answer?        alter table movie_archive alter column RecordID INTEGER Not null;    This is what i put in.  Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'UQ__Movie_Ar__FBDF78C84C0144E4' is dependent on column 'RecordID'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN RecordID failed because one or more objects access this column.      this is the error i got.

Comment: ok you cannot alter if you have unique constraint on that column. drop that and recreate it